# Locate the runes near the Hound Pits in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

It looks like the runes are under a pile of rubble. But how do you get access to them?

Comment: A screenshot would make this easier to answer, and to tell us what mission you're on.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rune in the sewers under the pub, which you access as part of the story. If you haven't been to the sewers yet, you need to wait before you can collect that rune.

Comment: Depending on where the icon shows up.